# Problems while trying to prove the Contracted Epsilon Identity. (Levi-Civita symbol)

Tags: vector-analysis

I've been trying to prove the contracted epsilon identity ($ \varepsilon_{ijk}\varepsilon_{klm} = \dots$) with the help of [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TIE43zDsr50). The proof writes the Levi-Civita symbol as a determinant, then multiplies the matrices and takes the determinant to get to the result.

I get the big picture of the proof, there's just one thing I don't really understand.

At some point, he gets the following value for the first row, first column of the matrix:

$$\delta_{i1}\delta_{1i}+\delta_{i2}\delta_{2i}+\delta_{i3}\delta_{3i}.$$

He says (around the 8:20 mark) that this equals $3$. Now, as far as I know, this can be written as:

$$\sum_{x=1}^3 \delta_{ix}\delta_{xi} = \delta_{ii}.$$

Why does this equal $3$? It would only be right if you were taking $\sum_{i=1}^3$ of the result.

The next part I understand, but I think he also made an error:

$$\delta_{j1}\delta_{1i}+\delta_{j2}\delta_{2i}+\delta_{j3}\delta_{3i}.$$

He says that equals $\delta_{jp}\delta_{pi}$. I say it equals $\sum_{p=1}^3\delta_{jp}\delta_{pi}$, though his final result is correct ($\delta_{ji}$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe summation notation is being used. When a dummy index appears twice, it is being summed over all of its possible values.

So $\delta_{i1}\delta_{1i} + \delta_{i2}\delta_{2i} + \delta_{i3}\delta_{3i}$ really means

$$\sum_{i=1}^3(\delta_{i1}\delta_{1i} + \delta_{i2}\delta_{2i} + \delta_{i3}\delta_{3i}).$$

As $\delta_{xi} = \delta_{ix}$, $\delta_{ix}\delta_{xi} = \delta_{ix}^2 = \delta_{ix}$, the sum reduces to

\begin{align*}
&\sum_{i=1}^3(\delta_{i1} + \delta_{i2} + \delta_{i3})\\
=& (\delta_{11} + \delta_{12} + \delta_{13}) + (\delta_{21} + \delta_{22} + \delta_{23}) + (\delta_{31} + \delta_{32} + \delta_{33})\\
=& (1 + 0 + 0) + (0 + 1 + 0) + (0 + 0 + 1)\\
=&\ 3.
\end{align*}

As for the simplification of $\delta_{j1}\delta_{1i}+\delta_{j2}\delta_{2i}+\delta_{j3}\delta_{3i}$, your expression and his agree once you realise that he is using summation notation; his notation is shorthand for what you've written explicitly.

Comment: I figured that might be the problem, but I don't understand where that summation comes from. He doesn't write it in his original matrices and the entries in his matrices never contain the same index twice, so where does the sum come from?

Comment: He mentions the summation convention he is using in the [first video](http://youtu.be/N1YBgU-xu6A?t=1m52s). I don't really understand what you mean by "where does the sum come from?"

Comment: I think I might be misunderstanding the summation convention. The (wrong?) way I see it, the Summation symbol is simply left out if an index is present twice. The way I think it might be is that if an index appears twice, it always becomes a summation. Which one is correct? If the first one is correct, then what I mean with my question is: There's a summation is his formula, but it is not written explicitly. Where does this summation come from? If you literally just write down the matrix multiplication then there would be no summation because it's not present in either matrices.